# Display attributed text in textview in swift 3?

Tags: html, swift3, textview

I want to display text in Italic ,bold which is received from server .
< p > < b > < i > hello < /i > < /b > < i >world< /i >< /p > so,

```
responseObj!["text"] = "<p><b><i>hello</i></b><i>world</></p>"
     if let postText:String = responseObj!["text"] as? String{
          let str = try NSAttributedString(data: postText.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
      self.textView.attributedText = str
    }
```

when i am adding like this means my text displays normal without applying bold & italic . I want text to be displayed in bold ,italic .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: Updated Swift 4**

Create an `extension` for `String`:

```
extension String {
    func htmlAttributedString(fontSize: CGFloat = 17.0) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let fontName = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize).fontName
        let string = self.appending(String(format: "<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>", fontName, fontSize))
        guard let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }

        guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString (
             data: data,
             options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
             documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
        return html
    }
}
```

**Invoke it anywhere in your project:**

```
text.htmlAttributedString() // will set fontSize with 17.0 which is the default value


text.htmlAttributedString(fontSize: 14.0) // pass your required fontSize
```

> Note, that `let string = self.appending(String(format: "<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>", fontName, fontSize))` is used to keep the string font as same as the font used in default iOS platform.

To set the string on `UITextView` use:

```
textView.attributedText = textToBeConverted.htmlAttributedString() ?? ""
```

**RESULT:**

[image: RESULT]

Comment: it should be string

Comment: `?? ""` used to unwrap the value in the variable where `""` is the default value.

In simple English, If `textToBeConverted.htmlAttributedString()` is nil then `textView.attributedText` should have `""` as default.

Comment: It's not working for this format <p><span style="color: #000000;">Experience royalty i</span><br /><span style="color: #000000;"> An address that is a possession of pride</span></p>

I have tried with uiwebview loadHtmString but not working and uilabel but no luck. is there any problem in this html format, how to display this format?

Comment: have you tried setting the `attributeText` property of `textView`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Attributed text to UITextView from below function,

```
//HTML to Attributed text
func stringFromHtml(string: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
do {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    if let d = data {
        let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                         options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                         documentAttributes: nil)
        return str
    }
} catch {
}
return nil
}

//This will give you attributed text which you have to assign to your UITextView. and whatever string having html tag that you have to pass inside this function.

//Below code will conver attributed text to HTML Text
//Attributed to HTML text

    let attrStr = self.txtView.attributedText
    let documentAttributes = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
    do {
        let htmlData = try attrStr?.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, (attrStr?.length)!), documentAttributes:documentAttributes)
        if let htmlString = String(data:htmlData!, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8) {
            print(htmlString)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("error creating HTML from Attributed String")
    }
```

Comment: I only need <b>hello</b>

Comment: This code can be work to convert HTML to Attributed and Attributed to HTML Vice-versa. It won't be easy to generate as per your requirements. You can check above code by giving input so you will get exact output.

Comment: Ok Thank you . I will check

Comment: Yeah sure... :)